# What 2nd-order optimization algorithms have convergence guarantees for strictly- but not strongly-convex problems?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

A function $f$ is strictly convex if
$$f((1 - \lambda)x + \lambda y) \le (1 - \lambda)f(x) + \lambda f(y)$$
with equality if and only if $x$ and $y$ are equal.
This implies that the second derivative of $f$ is positive-definite.
A strongly convex function is one where we also have strictly positive lower bounds on the smallest eigenvalue of $d^2f$.
Your average optimization textbook like Nocedal and Wright will prove the convergence of Newton-type algorithms under an assumption of strong convexity.

I'm interested in convex optimization problems that are strict but not strong.
The silliest example would be, say,
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{4}\|Kx - g\|^4 + h^*x$$
but there could be higher powers or sums of different powers or what have you.
The second derivative doesn't stay bounded away from zero near the minimizer, and yet the problem is strictly convex so there must be a unique minimizer.
**What 2nd-order optimization algorithms have nice global convergence guarantees even for problems like this?**
I would imagine Newton line search might not but Newton trust region does.
Either way, I haven't seen this covered in standard textbooks on convex optimization.

Comment: You should probably search for the term "semi-smooth Newton".

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth What makes you suggest that? The problems I'm interested in are smooth, they just fail to be coercive (if you want to make an analogy with elliptic PDE theory).

Comment: Ah, yes, I misread that!